# SQL запрос в Yii2

Tags: sql, yii2

Здравствуйте.

Возникла такая проблема.

Есть SQL запрос:

```
$this->search = (new Query())
        ->select(['group.title', 'schedule.date', new Expression('ifnull(attendance.mark, :message)')])
        ->from('schedule')
        ->join('LEFT JOIN','attendance','schedule.id = attendance.schedule_id')
        ->join('INNER JOIN','group','schedule.group_id = group.id')
        ->where('attendance.mark IS NULL')
        ->params([':message' => 'Не отметили посещаемость']);
```

Он работает отлично.

Но как только я добавляю условие **AND schedule.date <= :delayDate**

и новый параметр  **':delayDate' => '2018-01-01 00:00:00'**:

```
$this->search = (new Query())
        ->select(['group.title', 'schedule.date', new Expression('ifnull(attendance.mark, :message)')])
        ->from('schedule')
        ->join('LEFT JOIN','attendance','schedule.id = attendance.schedule_id')
        ->join('INNER JOIN','group','schedule.group_id = group.id')
        ->where('attendance.mark IS NULL AND schedule.date <= :delayDate')
        ->params([':message' => 'Не отметили посещаемость' , ':delayDate' => '2018-01-01 00:00:00']);
```

Вылазит ошибка:

```
SQLSTATE[HY093]: 

Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

The SQL being executed was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `schedule` LEFT JOIN `attendance` ON schedule.id = attendance.schedule_id INNER JOIN `group` ON schedule.group_id = group.id WHERE attendance.mark IS NULL AND schedule.date <= '2018-01-01 00:00:00'
```

По идее, передаю два параметра: **message** и **delayDate**, использую их в запросе. Но он ругается.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Что-то текст запроса в коде не очень-то соответствует тексту запроса в сообщении об ошибке...

Comment: @Akina вот да. Тоже заметил. Ибо **SELECT COUNT(*)***

Comment: @Akina но вот почему.... хммммммммм

Comment: Наверное, потому, что ошибка в другом месте кода...

Comment: @Akina ваши предположения, где может быть ошибка? 
Я пока не вижу. (

Comment: Ну какие могут быть предположения? найдите и покажите в вопросе именно тот код, который приводит к ошибке - тогда и появится предмет для обсуждения.

Comment: @Akina я указал сначала рабочий код. Он прекрасно работает. После чего добавляю еще параметр и условие. Все ломается. 
Я не хочу с вами спорить, но считаю, что ошибка именно в этой части кода. Если вам для того, чтобы мне помочь, нужно больше информации, скажите что вам предоставить.

Comment: Проверьте, что ли, поведение РАБОЧЕГО (первого) кода, а именно посмотрите на MySQL в General Log, сколько запросов фреймворк отправляет на сервер, один или два? Потому как единственное предположение в том, что фреймворк "проявляет самодеятельность" и дополнительно пытается получить сведения о том, сколько записей отберёт запрос (иначе я даже представить не могу, откуда выплывает `COUNT(*)`)... PS. Сообщение об ошибке - это PHP-сообщение.

Comment: @Anatoliy.CHA, какого типа данных поле *schedule.date*?